# Drupal 7 -generell concept to implement generic content-type fields depending on individuell Usersettings

Tags: generics, drupal-7, content-type

english isn't my native tongue - so i hope you understand my point and please be lenient. ;-)

Im a drupal beginner, some weeks of studying now - reading many stuff in english but i need help to find the right way

im trying to generate generic content-types where the field.display.state should change on user driven setting actually stored in profile2. I fail to implement this dependecies in a propper way actually...

conditional fields act nice when only profile2 fields are involved
i looked also yet at 
hook_alter_form
rules
field permission

..and im actually a little bit confused which way can work and which way i should use

im not looking for made code but perhaps for s.t like best practice here for hints - tipps how the experts here handle such things links to the topic and so on

thanks for all answers
tom

Answer (score 0):

The best way by far is to do this with some (relatively) simple code.

First off, you need to create a simple module. More on that [here](https://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-your-first-module-drupal-module-development).

Once you have that, you need to alter the way the node is being displayed. The best hook for that is [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), which will allow you to override each field before it is rendered.

There you need to check that the content type is the one you want to change, perform your logic, and change the node object to be rendered. Finally, return the altered node object.

Assuming your module is `nodemodule` :

```
function nodemodule_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  global $user;
  if ($node->type=="my_content_type"){
     // Perform checks and whatnot here
     if($user->uid==123) {
       // Disable access to field_example
       $node->content['field_example']['#access'] = false;   
     }
  }

  return $node;
}
```

This is basically the equivalent of the user "not having permission" to see this field. The criteria here ( `uid` = 123 ) is pretty useless, but you can use your own.

Don't forget to flush all caches if you use this!

Another alternative is the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module, where you can set which groups can do what (view/edit/etc) on each field, and then use user hooks to alter the user groups. I'm sure there are other ways as well :)

Comment: oops only five mins to edit a comment....Does this $user - i think its an array - also has the values from profile2 of current logged in user? i need sthg. like                if user.profile2.dependingfield has value x ... {

Comment: I haven't used profile2, but from a brief look, you just need to load the profile data via something like `$profile_values = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid);`